# Architecture and methods used in LUIS and QnA maker (Microsoft Cognitive Services)

Tags: chatbot, azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

I have looked at the possibility of creating chatbots using LUIS and Q&A maker. But I haven't really found any good documentation on how they work. Are they based on Recurrent Neural Networks? Are they inspired by certain recent papers, or is there any papers that explain how they are constructed? What have NLP methods been applied?

Thanks :)

Comment: I think that exact algorithms are secrets of Microsoft. Most probably, they are somehow based on this [service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/linguistic-analysis-api/), which is a common NLP technique.